# Using Minitab to compute an upper confidence bound for std deviation.

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, confidence-interval

I've got a set of data and I want to answer the following:

```
Calculate an upper confidence bound with confidence level 95% for the population standard deviation of maximum pressure.
```

The set of data is

```
33.2, 41.8, 37.3, 40.2, 36.7, 39.1, 36.2, 41.8

36.0, 35.2, 36.7, 38.9, 35.8, 35.2, 40.1
```

We are learning how to use Minitab and we've been asked to solve this using Minitab. I only see an option to compute the one-sample t for the mean, and I'm unsure how to compute the one-sample t for standard deviation.

Edit: I just found the 1 variance computation and got this as the result:

95% Confidence Intervals

```
                         CI for         CI for
Variable  Method          StDev        Variance
C1        Chi-Square  (1.88, 4.06)  (3.54, 16.45)
          Bonett      (1.95, 3.91)  (3.79, 15.28)
```

Which of these is the answer I'm looking for? I'm not sure what Chi-square and Bonnett are?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do a one-sided confidence interval. (Your question is somewhat ambiguous. If you want the upper-*end* of a *two*-sided CI, then your procedure gives 16.45 for the variance.)

The
code generated by what I suppose to be the appropriate menu
choices (STAT > Basic > One variance > data in C1, Omit test, Option > Less than) is as follows:

```
 MTB > set c1
 DATA> 33.2, 41.8, 37.3, 40.2, 36.7, 39.1, 36.2, 41.8 
 DATA> 36.0, 35.2, 36.7, 38.9, 35.8, 35.2, 40.1
 DATA> end
 MTB > OneVariance C1;
 SUBC>   Confidence 95.0;
 SUBC>   Alternative -1.

 Test and CI for One Variance: C1 

 Method

 The chi-square method is only for the normal distribution.
 The Bonett method is for any continuous distribution.


 Statistics

 Variable   N  StDev  Variance
 C1        15   2.57      6.61


 95% One-Sided Confidence Intervals

                       Upper
                       Bound
                         for   Upper Bound
 Variable  Method      StDev  for Variance
 C1        Chi-Square   3.75         14.09
           Bonett       3.63         13.15
```

The above is from Minitab 16. (Bonnett's procedure does not assume the
data are normal.) I will leave it to you to figure out 
exactly what distribution theory Minitab is using to get the one-sided
chi-squared upper confidence *bound.*

In R, the computation for the upper-bound on the variance is:

```
 (14)*2.572^2/qchisq(.05, 14)
 ## 14.09493
```

Take the square root to get a bound for the SD.